# How to copy contents of a subdirectory in python

Tags: python

I am newbie to python, I am trying to achieve following task-

I have a directory **WP_Test** containing a sub-directory **test**, I want to copy all the files and folders inside this sub-directory **test** to another location.

I have following code but not working for me. Please try to help me achieving the solution to the task. Any help will be highly appreciated :)

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.walk(src).next()[1]:
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            print("Found directory!")
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
copytree("/home/user/Desktop/WP_Test", "/home/user/Desktop/something")
```

Comment: It's a possibility if you are on a windows machine you need '\' instead of '/'. Additionally I would check that those directories actually exist by finding the directory you want in your file explorer and either click the navigation bar (Windows) or run 'pwd' on a unix machine

Comment: Actually on Windows it should work with "/"

Comment: I am working on linux

Comment: A good debugging step would be adding some print statements in the `if (os.path.isdir(s))` block to see if it actually recognizes it as a dir

Comment: Can you help me achieve this task.. thanks

Comment: I am already using `if os.path.isdir(s):`

Comment: I am aware, add a `print("Found directory!")` line tabbed in below it

Comment: @EastonBornemeier it gives me this error `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: @EastonBornemeier Thanks for helping

Comment: Your indentation is off then. Make sure that it is at the same indentation level as the line below it.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to read up a little bit on python before trying to use libraries like this. :) It's hard to get things to work when the language is the thing blocking you from your task, rather than the concept.

Comment: I have updated my code in question as you said @EastonBornemeier

Comment: Is `os.walk(src).next()[1]` valid?  I get "AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'" as I expected I would.

Comment: When you run your program what is the output?

Comment: @EastonBornemeier attached the output to question

Comment: Your else: line isn't indented correctly.  Check the source and make sure everything has the same number of spaces.

Comment: Once you fix that, you'll get an AttributeError on the line I was questioning.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier `print("Found directory!")` this was having wrong indentation i fixed it, code is working now but not achieved the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully achieved the task, below is the code-

```
dst = '/home/user/Desktop/something'
    src = '/home/user/Desktop/WP_Test'
    def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
        for item in os.listdir(src):
            i = os.path.join(src, item)
            for item in os.listdir(i):
                s = os.path.join(i, item)
                d = os.path.join(dst, item)
                if os.path.isdir(s):
                    shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
                else:
                    shutil.copy2(s, d)
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    copytree(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by changing

```
for item in os.walk(src).next()[1]:
```

To:

```
  for item in os.listdir(src):
```