# Copy specific subdirectories by its name with Python

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil, copytree

If I have a folder which has multiple subfolders, each has same structure sub1, sub2 and sub3:

```
├─a
│  ├─sub1
│  ├─sub2
│  └─sub3
├─b
│  ├─sub1
│  ├─sub2
│  └─sub3
└─c
    ├─sub1
    ├─sub2
    └─sub3
...
```

I want to copy `sub1` and `sub2` if there are image files inside and ignore other subfolders (`sub3...`) while keeping tree structure of directory. This is expected result:

```
├─a
│  ├─sub1
│  └─sub2
├─b
│  ├─sub1
│  └─sub2
└─c
    ├─sub1
    └─sub2
...
```

What should I do to get expected result? I have try following code but it only copy `sub1`, `sub2` and `sub3`, I got `TypeError: copy() takes no arguments (1 given)`.

Thanks to @PrasPJ.

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil
import fnmatch

src_dir= ['C:/Users/User/Desktop/source/input']      # List of source dirs
included_subdirs = ['sub1', 'sub2']        # subdir to include from copy
dst_dir = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/source/output'     # folder for the destination of the copy
for root_path in src_dir:
    #print(root_path)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path): # recurse walking
        for dir in included_subdirs:
            #print(dir)
            if dir in dirs:
                source = os.path.join(root,dir)
                f_dst = source.replace(root_path, dst_dir)
                print (source, f_dst)
                for file in os.listdir(source):
                    print(file)
                    if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
                        shutil.copytree(source, f_dst)
```

Reference related:

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/356380/how-to-copy-folders-directories-using-python

[Python shutil copytree: use ignore function to keep specific files types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487578/python-shutil-copytree-use-ignore-function-to-keep-specific-files-types)

[How to copy contents of a subdirectory in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333182/how-to-copy-contents-of-a-subdirectory-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you are trying to use dictionary's copy function which is wrong

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil
import fnmatch

list_of_dirs_to_copy = ['C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/input'] # List of source dirs
included_subdirs = ['sub1', 'sub2']  # subdir to include from copy
dest_dir = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/output'     # folder for the destination of the copy
for root_path in list_of_dirs_to_copy:
    print(root_path)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path): # recurse walking
        for dir in included_subdirs:
            print(dir)
            if dir in dirs:
                source = os.path.join(root,dir)
                f_dest = source.replace(root_path, dest_dir)
                print source, f_dest 
                shutil.copytree(source,f_dest)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question, if I want to add one more condition to decide to copy sub1 and sub2 or not by examining if they have files inside endwith 'jpg' or 'jpeg' or not? What should I do?

Comment: do you have only files in sub1 and sub2?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil
import fnmatch

list_of_dirs_to_copy = ['C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/input'] # List of source dirs
included_subdirs = ['sub1', 'sub2']  # subdir to include from copy
dest_dir = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/output'     # folder for the destination of the copy
for root_path in list_of_dirs_to_copy:
    print(root_path)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path): # recurse walking
        for dir in included_subdirs:
            print(dir)
            if dir in dirs:
                source = os.path.join(root,dir)
                for f in os.listdir(source):
                    print os.path.join(source,f)
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source,f)) and (f.endswith("jpg") or f.endswith("jpeg")): 
                        f_dest = source.replace(root_path, dest_dir)
                        print source, f_dest 
                        shutil.copytree(source,f_dest)
                        break # found any one matching file
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I need to ask one more question: what if I copy subfolders a, b and c... only if in both sub1 and sub2 have image files?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the update

```
for root_path in list_of_dirs_to_copy:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path): # recurse walking
        path_to_copy = {}
        for dir in included_subdirs:
            if dir in dirs:
                source = os.path.join(root,dir)
                for f in os.listdir(source):
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source,f)) and (f.endswith("jpg") or f.endswith("jpeg")):
                        f_dest = source.replace(root_path, dest_dir)
                        path_to_copy.update({source: f_dest})
        if len(path_to_copy) == len(included_subdirs):
            for source, f_dest in path_to_copy.iteritems():
                shutil.copytree(source,f_dest)
```